# Need special character after every line in linux vi mode

Tags: linux, vi

I got a text file with many line. I need a separator for each line.

### Eg ..

```
asdfgh

Hjkll

Etyjik

Yuiilpm
```

### Output should be like this..

```
asdfgh

+++++++

Hjkll

+++++++

Etyjik

+++++++

Yuiilpm

+++++++
```

It would be any special character...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it need to be vi or is it OK if it's done in the shell? In the shell for example you can simply do `awk '{print $0; print "+++++++"}' < file.txt`

Comment: I'm new to Linux and can u tell in detail. Don't have knowledge about shell and awk... Kindly guide me where to start about linux ,shell,awk ,vi etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this awk one liner -

```
awk '{ print; print "+++++++" }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print}NR%2==0{print "+++++++\n"}sub(/Yuiilpm/,"\n+++++++")' file
asdfgh

+++++++

Hjkll

+++++++

Etyjik

+++++++

Yuiilpm

+++++++
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a solution in vi/vim, you can do this:

```
:global /./ execute "normal! A\<Enter>\<Enter>+++++++"
```

Explaination:

- `:global` - Run a command against all lines matching a pattern
- `/./` - Pattern which matches any single character (won't match empty lines)
- `execute ...` - Execute a command
- `normal!` - Run the following as if they were typed in normal mode with no remapping of keys
- `A\<Enter>\<Enter>+++++++` - Append two new lines followed by the special string

This can be shortened down to:

```
:g/./exe "norm! A\<cr>\<cr>+++++++"
```